# How do you use jquery to edit unordered list items

Tags: jquery, list

How can I edit the innerText property of a li inside a ul using jquery?

I used this approach and wasn't able to get it working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var lis = $("#SuperTextbox1_Results li").get();
            for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
                lis[i].innerText = "<lable>added text!<label>";
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SuperTextbox1_Results").children('li').each(function(){
        $(this).text('blah');
    });
});
```

Comment: How would I use this to concat instead of replace the li value?

Comment: What if the concat is at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('#SuperTextBox1_Results li').text('whatever you want');
```

Or, if you want the label:

```
$('#SuperTextBox1_Results li').html('<label>whatever you want</label');
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
 $('#SuperTextBox1_Results li').each(function(){$(this).text('whatever');})
```